# How to configure a (woocommerce) product by just clicking buttons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a webshop (woocommerce) where customers can customise a product by clicking 7 out of 30 buttons. Each button is in fact a sort of option and could be seen as a hidden checkbox.
I tried and looked at different Woocommerce plugins but nothing works as I want it to work.
I know woocommerce can work with direct order links, so I thought it could be possible to create dynamic urls from the clicked buttons and pass url to the shopping cart, but in fact this would mean all buttons are different options but in fact they're not.
Example: A mix of nuts or candy. The customer can select op to 7 different types of nuts or candy and the shopping cart should say: Nut mix - nuts 1, nuts 2, nuts 3, etc.
The price is always the same, no matter if the customer selects 2 or 7 kinds of nuts or candy.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could save it as an variable product with attributes like "nut1", "nut2", ...
How to do this is explained [here.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/)

And take a look at [this](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-variation-link/). I think it might be exactly what you want to do! With the plugin you can add your set attributes for the product via GET variables.

Comment: Ok, so every kind of nut as a new attribute and not one attribute for all different nuts

Comment: Yes, thats what i would recommend to do. So you could add/remove all variations like you wish.